# Why don't we take minimum of the low time of child and parent node in finding articulation point algorithm using a time variable

Tags: algorithm, recursion, graph

One approach to find articulation point is to maintain discovery time of a node. Here in a disc[] array we have maintained the discovery time of a vertex, and in another array low[], we have kept the minimum of the discovery times of its child which is an parent of its root.

what we have done is, recursively called the function for all the adjacent nodes if it is not visited. and if it is already visited we just took the min of low[u] and dist[v]. where u is the parent v.
Why this is not min(low[u],low[v]).

[Here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/articulation-points-or-cut-vertices-in-a-graph/) is an explanation of above algorithm.

```
// A Java program to find articulation points in an undirected graph
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;

// This class represents an undirected graph using adjacency list
// representation
class Graph
{
private int V;   // No. of vertices

// Array  of lists for Adjacency List Representation
private LinkedList<Integer> adj[];
int time = 0;
static final int NIL = -1;

// Constructor
Graph(int v)
{
    V = v;
    adj = new LinkedList[v];
    for (int i=0; i<v; ++i)
        adj[i] = new LinkedList();
}

//Function to add an edge into the graph
void addEdge(int v, int w)
{
    adj[v].add(w);  // Add w to v's list.
    adj[w].add(v);  //Add v to w's list
}

// A recursive function that find articulation points using DFS
// u --> The vertex to be visited next
// visited[] --> keeps tract of visited vertices
// disc[] --> Stores discovery times of visited vertices
// parent[] --> Stores parent vertices in DFS tree
// ap[] --> Store articulation points
void APUtil(int u, boolean visited[], int disc[],
            int low[], int parent[], boolean ap[])
{

    // Count of children in DFS Tree
    int children = 0;

    // Mark the current node as visited
    visited[u] = true;

    // Initialize discovery time and low value
    disc[u] = low[u] = ++time;

    // Go through all vertices aadjacent to this
    Iterator<Integer> i = adj[u].iterator();
    while (i.hasNext())
    {
        int v = i.next();  // v is current adjacent of u

        // If v is not visited yet, then make it a child of u
        // in DFS tree and recur for it
        if (!visited[v])
        {
            children++;
            parent[v] = u;
            APUtil(v, visited, disc, low, parent, ap);

            // Check if the subtree rooted with v has a connection to
            // one of the ancestors of u
            low[u]  = Math.min(low[u], low[v]);

            // u is an articulation point in following cases

            // (1) u is root of DFS tree and has two or more chilren.
            if (parent[u] == NIL && children > 1)
                ap[u] = true;

            // (2) If u is not root and low value of one of its child
            // is more than discovery value of u.
            if (parent[u] != NIL && low[v] >= disc[u])
                ap[u] = true;
        }

        // Update low value of u for parent function calls.
        else if (v != parent[u])
            low[u]  = Math.min(low[u], disc[v]);
    }
}

// The function to do DFS traversal. It uses recursive function APUtil()
void AP()
{
    // Mark all the vertices as not visited
    boolean visited[] = new boolean[V];
    int disc[] = new int[V];
    int low[] = new int[V];
    int parent[] = new int[V];
    boolean ap[] = new boolean[V]; // To store articulation points

    // Initialize parent and visited, and ap(articulation point)
    // arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
    {
        parent[i] = NIL;
        visited[i] = false;
        ap[i] = false;
    }

    // Call the recursive helper function to find articulation
    // points in DFS tree rooted with vertex 'i'
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        if (visited[i] == false)
            APUtil(i, visited, disc, low, parent, ap);

    // Now ap[] contains articulation points, print them
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        if (ap[i] == true)
            System.out.print(i+" ");
}

// Driver method
public static void main(String args[])
{
    // Create graphs given in above diagrams
    System.out.println("Articulation points in first graph ");
    Graph g1 = new Graph(5);
    g1.addEdge(1, 0);
    g1.addEdge(0, 2);
    g1.addEdge(2, 1);
    g1.addEdge(0, 3);
    g1.addEdge(3, 4);
    g1.AP();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Articulation points in Second graph");
    Graph g2 = new Graph(4);
    g2.addEdge(0, 1);
    g2.addEdge(1, 2);
    g2.addEdge(2, 3);
    g2.AP();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Articulation points in Third graph ");
    Graph g3 = new Graph(7);
    g3.addEdge(0, 1);
    g3.addEdge(1, 2);
    g3.addEdge(2, 0);
    g3.addEdge(1, 3);
    g3.addEdge(1, 4);
    g3.addEdge(1, 6);
    g3.addEdge(3, 5);
    g3.addEdge(4, 5);
    g3.AP();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is specific to find articulation points. when we iterate through child V of children of node U, the U will be articulation point if low(V)==dist(U). But if U belongs to another cycle which is processed before handling U->V, then dist(U)>low(U). Because U can go back to its ancestor. In this case, if we use

```
low[u] = min(low[u],low[v])
```

then low(V)=low(U) when handling V. back to post handling of U, the dist[U]<=low[V] is not true (because low[V]=low[U]<dist[U]). Then U will not be an articulation point any more, which is flawed.

Please note that this will not apply to find bridges or Trajan's SCC, as both don't care about U is the root of a cycling case (dist[U]==low[v]).

Personally, I prefer using dist[u] all the time, as it's consistent, and the definition of low is also much clear.

good article: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/71146

Answer (score 1):

let's say U is the parent and V be its neighbor or child in DFS spanning tree. A simple scenario in which it will fail could be when there is a BackEdge from U to one of its ancestors and there is a BackEdge from V to U. Consider below graph

[image: Lets take this graph]

Credits: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/71146

Answer (score 0):

I think you have slightly misinterpreted the visited vertex case.

In DFS of an undirected graph, whenever we find an edge from vertex u to vertex v such that v is already visited, it means that it is a back edge and that v is an ancestor of u (unless of-course v is u's parent).

Now from the given code, the motive of low[u] is to store the lowest discovery time vertex reachable from any of the vertices in the sub tree rooted with u. (i.e. including u)

So when we discover an edge u->v such that v is an ancestor of u (and not its parent) that means that this vertex v can very well be the vertex with the lowest disc. time that is reachable from sub tree rooted at u. So we update low[u] as minimum of its current value and disc. time of the ancestor vertex v that is reachable from it.

Now why not low[v], simply because if the vertex x being tested for being an A.P. is below v, then `low[x] = disc[v]` works enough to prove it is not an AP, and if it is above v, then there will be a step - > `low[x] = min(low[x], low[v])`

Answer (score 0):

First things first:

`disc[]`: It answers a simple question, when was a particular vertex "discovered" in the depth-first-search?, which means it assigns a number to the the vertex in the order it is found in the `dfs`.(Is not changed)

`low[x]`: It answers yet another simple question, "what is lowest level vertex `x` can climb to". (Is subject to change in every iteration)

`back-edge`: An edge which connects a vertex to an already visited vertex which is not its immediate parent

Now, in the given piece of code, the following section:

```
else if (v != parent[u])
    low[u]  = Math.min(low[u], disc[v]);
```

refers to the scenario when there exists a back-edge. On encountering a back-edge we update the `low` value of parent with the lowest-level vertex it can climb to (if its discovery time is lesser that the lower value of parent).

Its difficult to find an example where changing this piece of code to the following

```
else if (v != parent[u])
    low[u]  = Math.min(low[u], low[v]);
```

would break the algorithm. That being said, both these pieces of code have semantically very different meaning.

`Math.min(low[u], low[v]);` simply refers that if the child has a back-edge, so will its immediate parent, while `Math.min(low[u], disc[v]);` semantically means that the `low` value of a vertex is the lowest level vertex it can climb to.